# MySQL function that counts occurrences

Tags: mysql

So I have a table with the following columns: `id, Fname, Lname, city and desc`

What I am trying to accomplish is to create a function that counts how many employees are working in each city.

Normally I would just use something like 
`select city, count(*) as NumofEmp from employee group by city`
but at the moment I have to create a function for this. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Reading the docs would be a good start. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select city, count(name) as NumofEmp from employee group by city
```

Comment: Please read the actual question: **I have to create a function for this. How could I accomplish this?**

Comment: Ok..within the function what will be there?